# Can't catch any Pokemon or get items from Pokestops?

Tags: pokemon-go

My Pokemon Go seems to be glitched. I can't get any Pokemon or Pokeballs from PokeStops.

What can I do?

Comment: Did you restart the app? Which mobile OS are you using? What does exactly happen ("Try again later" message or "Too far away")? Please refine your questions by adding more detail.

Comment: Maybe because you have a bad internet

Comment: Try again later, I had this problem this morning, returned to normality after about 20 mins

Comment: @Bonus Question is locked so I can't answer, but I've read that this happens when Niantic's algorithm catches you for spoofing your location. It makes all Pokemon run and stops spin but always say Try again. It's called a soft ban. They let you play again after the amount of time passes that it would have taken you to actually travel there

Comment: Ta for the info. I guess their algo can sometimes get confused, but algos aren't perfect. Hopefully they don't keep a count of such soft bans and perma-ban you without more evidence, in my case there was no spoofing, just the normal train commute.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to clear the app's data in your phone settings (or delete the app on iPhone). Everything is backed up on the cloud, so any progress will be saved. Then reboot your phone. Once  it has restarted, open the app (or reinstall the app on iPhone) Then log in to your account, and that *should* fix the issue.